# Database created on localhost is not visible in mysql server management

Tags: mysql

I am connecting mysql using nodejs .Connection is established.Database is created ,i am able to retrieve all the data but where does my database resides .I am not able to find it in mysql server management studio.

output:
server started
Connected!
Database created

Code:
var con = mysql.createConnection({
        host: "localhost",
          user: "root",
          database: "manavdb"

```
  });

  con.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Connected!");
    con.query("SELECT * FROM customers", function (err, result, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(result);
      });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is on the same computer (host) that the `NodeJS` process is running:

`mysql://root@localhost:3306/manavdb` ?

`mysql://root@127.0.0.1:3306/manavdb` ?

Do you run this `NodeJS` instance on the same computer that you are trying to connect to the DB from the MySQL Server Management?

Comment: yes nodejs instance and mysql server management are running on the same computer

Comment: Right, so your DB should be on those locations that I pointed out. Default settings should work. Why don't you try using a different admin tool? https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/admin/.

Comment: i got it .The database was created on phpmyadmin because i was using xampp server  .Database is created on localhost.